# Video link googlevideos on jwplayer

Tags: file, video, hyperlink, mp4, jwplayer

I can not place a link inside of jwplayer, I believe the problem is in code because there is no extension. When I try to download the link it gives me `.mp4` extension but not on live streaming.

```html
<div id='playeraheCgtDYddkW'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
     jwplayer('playeraheCgtDYddkW').setup({
         file: 'http://r19---sn-c0q7ln7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=54cd7d1bcfa4d604&itag=22&source=picasa&ip=87.250.55.188&ipbits=0&expire=1391127921&sparams=expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,source&signature=835780952812E6EF90478066DFF762197780B59C.8168FF6496A4707C70F3FD726ED8769B473E6DD5&key=cms1&begin=0&cm2=0&cms_redirect=yes&ms=nxu&mt=1388535980&mv=m',
         image: 'https://www.longtailvideo.com/content/images/jw-player/lWMJeVvV-876.jpg',
         title: 'sa',
         width: '100%',
         aspectratio: '16:9',
         fallback: 'false',
         primary: 'flash'
     });
</script>
```

This is the link: [link](http://r19---sn-c0q7ln7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=54cd7d1bcfa4d604&itag=22&source=picasa&ip=87.250.55.188&ipbits=0&expire=1391127921&sparams=expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,source&signature=835780952812E6EF90478066DFF762197780B59C.8168FF6496A4707C70F3FD726ED8769B473E6DD5&key=cms1&begin=0&cm2=0&cms_redirect=yes&ms=nxu&mt=1388535980&mv=m).

Comment: Google Videos are not supported. The only 3rd party format that is supported officially by JW Player is YouTube.

Comment: Yes i know, but i am asking how to get the mp4 downloading file of the google video link as streaming... I need only extension of link to be mp4

Comment: Just set the player's type variable to mp4

Answer (score -1):

Let add .mp4 at end of the link:

`http://r19---sn-c0q7ln7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=54cd7d1bcfa4d604&itag=22&source=picasa&ip=87.250.55.188&ipbits=0&expire=1391127921&sparams=expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,source&signature=835780952812E6EF90478066DFF762197780B59C.8168FF6496A4707C70F3FD726ED8769B473E6DD5&key=cms1&begin=0&cm2=0&cms_redirect=yes&ms=nxu&mt=1388535980&mv=m&filename=name.mp4`

Comment: Not work at all!